# Can you use a laravel app to serve theContent() of a Wordpress page?

Tags: laravel, wordpress

I wish to have a Wordpress site, but have certain paths served with an application written in Laravel.

For example:

- [www.mySite.com](http://www.mySite.com)   << just serves the normal Wordpress homepage
- [www.mySite.com/blah](http://www.mySite.com/blah) << also handles as part of the Wordpress site
- [www.mySite.com/blah2](http://www.mySite.com/blah2) << theContent() is pulled from Laravel, but it's wrapped in the normal Wordpress templating engine.

So, the /blah2 page will look and feel just like the rest of the site, because it's using the templates/headers/footers of templates in Wordpress.  However, I'm just injecting theContent() from what I pull from the Laravel code.

I suppose I could just replicate the Wordpress templates in a totally separate Laravel site, but I thought it might be simpler to use the same templates.  Also, if they were two different sites, then I'd need [www.mySite.com](http://www.mySite.com), and [www.mySite2.com](http://www.mySite2.com), which I do not want.  I want the two to look seemless.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to write a plugin in WordPress to be able to pull the data from the database that is being populated by Laravel.

An easier method, depending on where your Laravel database is sitting, would be to handle it in WordPress using raw PHP.

There could be multiple ways to address this based on your exact setup.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by pulling it out of the database.  The output of the Laravel page isn't stored in a database.  To clarify, I'm talking about executing the Laravel page, capturing the HTTP body, then replacing theContent with the that captured output.

Comment: I understand now. Not sure how you can achieve that, however, you can consider saving the HTP body on a database on your Laravel side. The column type cab be text to ensure you can capture a large amount of textual data. Once you save your HTTP body, the WordPress side can consume the HTTP body from your Laravel site. All the best and hopefully you will come up with a simple and practical solution.